# Instalar plugin wordpress na maquina local

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou fazendo um site no wordpress, o problema é que como sou novo estou testando tudo na minha maquina local, para isso configurei o apache e instalei o wordpress.

no arquivo /etc/hosts configurei meu wordpress com a seguinte rota:

```
127.0.0.1       question.com.br question
```

meu problema é que agora quero instalar meu primeiro plugin e deparei com a tela onde ele me pede o Hostname, e não faço ideia de qual seja.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

**UPDATE**

melhorou um pouco minha situação acrescentando a linha

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

mas ele começou a instalar mas deu o seguinte erro na saida:

```
Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/profile-builder.2.3.1.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not create directory.
```

é algum problema de permissão na pasta?

eu já tentei os seguintes comando na minha pasta mas não deram certo:

```
maquinha@maquinha-desktop-1 /usr/share $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data wordpress/
maquinha@maquinha-desktop-1 /usr/share $ sudo chmod -R g+rw wordpress/
```

essa é a minha saida da permissões para o comando `ls -l`

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   418 Abr  9  2014 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  7210 Nov 22  2014 readme.html
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  4892 Abr  9  2014 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x  9 www-data www-data  4096 Fev 22 10:52 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data   271 Abr  9  2014 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  4795 Abr  9  2014 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  2412 Fev 22 17:11 wp-config.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  3087 Abr  9  2014 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data  4096 Fev 22 10:52 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  2932 Abr  9  2014 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x 12 www-data www-data  4096 Fev 22 10:52 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  2380 Abr  9  2014 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  2359 Abr  9  2014 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 32847 Nov 22  2014 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  8235 Abr  9  2014 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 10880 Abr  9  2014 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data 25665 Abr  9  2014 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  4026 Abr  9  2014 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data  3015 Abr  9  2014 xmlrpc.php
```

**UPDATE2**

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Fev 22 10:52 akismet
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   30 Abr  9  2014 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Fev 22 17:39 miniorange-login-openid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pode fazer download dos plugins descompactar e colocar na pasta "wp-content/plugins/", depois é só activar directo no painel de administração, ou adiciona a linha seguinte ao wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Com esta configuração também vai conseguir fazer upgrade ao Wordpress pelo painel de administração, sem ela quando houver actualização para o Wordpress vai aparecer o mesmo formulário que está a aparecer agora...

Comment: Você pode me dizer em que parte do arquivo adiciono essa linha? E depois preciso reiniciar algo, tipo o apache?

Comment: pode colar logo na linha a seguir ao inicio da tag php (<?php)

Comment: você pode me ajudar? Fiz um update na minha questão ainda não esta instalando.

Comment: Confirme que o apache esta a correr com o user www-data... e para apenas para despite tente instalar o plugin com permissões 777 na pasta wp-content.

Comment: Não funcionou eu tentei dar a mesma permissão a todos os subdiretórios.

Comment: sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

Comment: Altera so o caminho para o da sua instalação do WordPress

Comment: quando fiz esse comando ai que ele começou a reclamar de permissão, será que não são outra definições desse tipo `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct')` que estão faltando?

Comment: Sei que não é de todo uma boa prática mas tenta fazer `chmod 777 -R CaminhoParaSeuWordpress/wp-content/plugins` a ver se fica... como é seu sistema de testes e para não perder mais tempo com isso pode instalar o plugin manualmente... faz download do plugin descomprime e cola na pasta wp-content/plugins/

Comment: então eu fiz isso eu baixei o plugin decompactei e colei a pasta inteira dentro da pasta de plugins. Mas não vejo o meu plugin na lista;

Comment: confirma que só existe uma pasta.... por exemplo se o plugin se chama `exemplo/` tem que ficar `wp-content/plugins/exemplo/` não pode ficar  `wp-content/plugins/exemplo/exemplo/ `

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36132/discussion-between-marcius-leandro-and-antonio-campos).